# Почему контекст базы данных теряет пользователей?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Столкнулся с проблемой, найти решение которой особо не удалось.
Делаю страничку проектов. При добавлении нового проекта заполняю все данные, они корректно передаются в контроллер (в данном случае интересуют только SelectedUsers):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все айдишники пользователей корректны, пользователи успешно определяются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю новый project, внедряю в него все переданные раннее данные, все хорошо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После `_context.SaveChangesAsync();` проверяю контекст БД, все хорошо, записи присутствуют:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только я выхожу за пределы метода - данные ТОЛЬКО о SelectedUsers пропадают...

На всякий случай вот код метода Create:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так? Пытался максимально подробно описать проблему.

Comment: Есть уточняющий вопрос... > данные ТОЛЬКО о SelectedUsers пропадают.. - прошу прощения, а откуда они пропадают? Если они пропадают из базы - то это просто Мистика с большой буквы... я мог бы попробовать запустить проект у себя, но тогда нельзя ли его как то полодить так, чтобы можно было "скачать и запустить"?

Comment: Для начала добавьте везде `await` к вызовам асинхронных методов. `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: Код надо текстом вставлять.

Answer (score 1):

Господа! Опять-таки совершил глупые ошибки.

1. Действительно упустил пару await`ов, но конкретно на эту проблему это не влияло
2. Не хватало Include в коде. С ними все "зафурычило".
   Спасибо!